# Combining multiple atom feeds into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feed, atom-feed

I have 4 resources and I'd like to provide an atom feed for each one but I don't want to ask people sign up for 4 feeds (cos they won't) so is there a guide that explains the best way to combine multiple atom feeds into one master feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. So far I've found [yahoo pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) and [rss mix](http://www.rssmix.com/) that can do this job.