# Tutorial to build rss feed scroller in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Where can I find good tutorials to display RSS feed scroller in a Ruby on Rails website. The feed URL is from an external source like feedburner. feedzirra gem could be used here, but it involves curl installation and other supporting gems. I want something where feeds can be pulled without gems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean a js feedscroller or something like feedly?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All I want is to fetch top 10 posts from an external RSS feed and display in my sample blog sidebar. No need of Javascript part.

Comment: OK. You can try out the RSS Module in Ruby: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rss/rdoc/RSS.html

Comment: Thanks again. It worked. If you can help me to merge different feeds into one as in feedly then that would be great.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263913/combining-multiple-atom-feeds-into-one

Answer (score 0):

**posts_controller**

```
def feed
       @posts = Post.where(‘status = ?’, AppConstants::APPROVAL_ACTIVE).order(“updated_at desc”).limit(10)
       posts_ids = @posts.pluck(‘id’)
       assets = Asset.where(‘ref_id IN (?) and default_image_id = ?’, posts_ids, AppConstants::DEFAULT_IMAGE_VALUE)
       @posts_default_image_hash = Hash.new
         assets.each{|asset|
             @posts_default_image_hash[asset.ref_id] = asset
        }
      respond_to do |format|
           format.html
           format.atom { render layout: false }
      end 
end
```

**feed.atom.builder**

```
atom_feed do |feed|
     feed.title “Domail Name!”
     feed.updated Time.now
     @posts.each do |post|
             next if post.updated_at.blank?
             url = “localhost:3000(domain Name)/#{post.id}/#{post.name}
             feed.entry post, url:url do |entry|
                   entry.title post.title
                  content = “<img src=#{@posts_default_image_hash[post.id].image_url} height=180 width=220>” + post.content
                 entry.content content, type: ‘html’
                 entry.author do |author|
                        author.name(“Author name”)
                end
           end
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get “feed/” => “posts#feed”, :as => :feed, :defaults => { :format => ‘atom’ }
resources :post do
end
```

**application.html.erb(layout)**

```
<head>
     <%= auto_discovery_link_tag :atom, “/feed” %>
</head>
```

**foooter.html.erb** (wherever u want)

your feed burner url

```
<a href=”http://feeds.feedburner.com/abc” target=’_blank’ >
       keep some RSS feed image here </a>
```